# C#: looking for file stream seek between 2 length

Tags: c#, filestream

I would like to copy the partial content of a file using `FileStream` seek.

1. the actual file stream length of the file = `98764`.
2. I want file content between length `200 and 5000`
3. If I am doing `fileStream.Seek(200, SeekOrigin.Begin)`, then this give me file content from `200 to 98764`, but I want from `200 and 5000`.

   ```
   public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
   {
       using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\test\tes1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
       {
           var actualFileStremSize = fileStream.Length;

           //fileStream.Seek(200, SeekOrigin.Begin);

           var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {
               Content = new StreamContent(fileStream),
           };

           using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test\tes1_partial_copy.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
           {
               await result.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
           }

           return result;
       }
     }
     }
   ```

Main Method,

```
     class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Get().Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Looking for a solution to get file content between 2 file stream length. Thanks,

Comment: Don’t use CopyToAsync, but just seek to position 200, read 4800 bytes and write this to the other stream. Also, your file IO is not async as you explicitly need to specify this in the constructor, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access

Comment: @ckuri, does this mean I can't achieve this using `CopyToAsync`? without write to other stream?

Comment: No you can’t, because CopyToAsync will read everything from the current position of the source stream until the end and write this to the target. Internally CopyToAsync works like I have written in my first comment anyway, just that it uses a fixed block size and only stops when reaching the end of stream.

Comment: I would use a BinaryStream or make sure the FileStream is using UTF8 encoding.  Most stream methods default to Ascii encoding which will remove non-printable characters.