# getting ProtocolViolationException and some bytes missing at end of file while copy

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, filestream

I have a file `test.txt` which is continuous written by an some external application and every 2 minute my I am copy the file through `web api` call.

Sometime I am getting `ProtocolViolationException` error (`Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.`) and as I know this may be thrown if the file being streamed is being written to at the same time.

Here is my code,

**Server Side**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test\test_copy.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                await Request.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return Ok<bool>(true);
    }
```

**Client Side**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\test\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            CopyFile(fileStream).Wait();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<bool> CopyFile(FileStream fileStream)
    {
        bool Success = false;

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:59805/api/Values", new StreamContent(fileStream));
            }
        }

        catch (ProtocolViolationException protocolViolationException)
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        return Success;
    }
```

As lots of resource saying we can suppress `ProtocolViolationException`and this works for me, but the `issue` is that sometimes some bytes at end of file is missing (entire file content copy is `not` happening)

Note - on every file copy I am not getting this error, but when receives this error, some bytes is missing.

Is there any suggestion. Do I need any `Flush`, etc. Thanks!

Comment: But how you define "entire file content" if file is being written at the same time you are trying to send it to your web api?

Comment: @Evk, this is what my concern. how to define this

Comment: But you are saying that "some bytes at end of file is missing". How do you define end of file? I mean something constantly writes data to a file, so end of file at the start of your request is not the same as end of file at the end of your request. So how do you know bytes are missing?

Comment: ideally `CopyToAsync` does this thing, copy till end of line. When I am checking my copy file content, last line has partial data

Comment: how to solve this, `something constantly writes data to a file, so end of file at the start of your request is not the same as end of file at the end of your request.`?

Comment: Well I honestly not sure how to do this in a good way. Best would be to not write and read the same file at the same time, but I guess you cannot change that. And why copy the same information over and over again? I mean you always copy from start to end, and that another process only appends new lines, so you copy the same information many times?

Comment: actually I real code, I am using `File Seek` not to read duplicate

Comment: will this approach possible, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091374/c-looking-for-file-stream-seek-between-2-length

Comment: Then remember fileStream.Length before copying and then only copy until this length and no more. You cannot use CopyTo for that, so have to do it by hand.

Comment: can you suggest me some code as I can't use `CopyTo`. reading between 2 length

Comment: Well, first do ReadAsync to the buffer of length you need, then do WriteAsync with that buffer.